# I can't Conda install Tesseract in a continuumio/anaconda3 Docker container

Tags: python, docker, tesseract, anaconda3

I am trying to use `RUN conda install -c conda-forge tesseract` in my dockerfile to install the tesseract-ocr package.  All my other conda install packages have worked fine using that method.  I've looked at the GIT for tesseractocr `https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/Dockerfile` and it seems that the references they have in their docker example are out of date since the links to some of the dependencies return 'not found'.

My base image is `continuumio/anaconda3`

How can I get this library to install in this docker container?

Comment: _I am trying to conda install -c conda-forge tesseract using a RUN command in my dockerfile._ How does that relate to Tesserocr? I'm not familiar with the libraries involved, so I'm struggling to follow your explanation.

Comment: Just edited the original question.  So, most other python packages / libraries that I've had to install in the docker image I have been able to use `RUN conda install ...(etc)'. I've used conda install for the tesserocr library for my local machine with no issue, but it won't run in the when building the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to close this out.  I used `conda install -y -c conda-forge tesseract`
with the `-y` being the operative function that allowed the process to complete.